# How to not make CSS modal get cut off in page?

Tags: html, css

I have a modal implemented in CSS and it is getting cut off at the bottom of the page:
[image]

I've tried the following style attributes:

```
style = "max-height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; margin: auto"
```

But I am unable to make the modal fit in the page, on mobile or desktop. How can I fix this?

**Update:**
Tried:

```
style = "max-height: 95vh; max-width: 95vw; overflow-y: auto;"
```

This gave some room at the bottom, but I still want the modal to fit in the page:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
I've updated my modal to:

```
class="modal" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 100vh; padding: 30px 0px 50px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; height: 90vh; z-index: 1000"
```

and my modal content to:

```
class="modal-content" style="height: 80vh; max-height: 600px; position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 95vw; max-width: 600px; border-radius: 4px; overflow: auto; box-sizing: border-box"
```

This seems to solve the problem I was having that caused the bottom button to get cut off; however, now, the header doesn't look right. It is pushed down. What can I do to fix this?:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CSS has the unit `vh` (**v**iewport **h**eight) for this.

```
max-height: 95vh; /* 95% of the viewport's height */
```

This works on any device, mobile or desktop, with [a supporting browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_length_vh). Even Internet Explorer 9 supports it.

Regarding the overflow, I recommend you `overflow-y` as `auto`, not `scroll`. The difference is that `scroll` will always result in a scrollbar, even if not needed.

Remember to also limit the `width` of the modal. Long playlist names might, especially on mobile devices, lead to unwanted layout results otherwise.

For `width`, the corresponding unit is `vw` (**v**iewport **w**idth).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So that left some room at the bottom; however, I still am aiming for the modal to fit in the screen. I will update the initial post with a screenshot after trying style = "max-height: 95vh; max-width: 95vw; overflow-y: auto;"

Comment: Make sure your modal has `box-sizing: border-box` to include paddings in `width` and `height` - otherwise those add to `max-height` resp. `max-width`. Honestly, your whole page should have that, as it is the much better *box-model*.

Comment: Thanks you. I have added the box_sizing style, but now the header is not looking right. Anything I can do to fix? I have updated the post.

Comment: The quick fix is to only apply the new box model to your modal. The clean fix is to go through all of your styles, and redefine width and possibly height based on the knowledge that the new box model means that width/height **includes** padding, as opposed to the classic box model, where paddings **add** to width/height.